# My Website is slow with Chrome. But not in any other browser even in Incognito

Tags: performance, google-chrome, web

I am fairly new to Web Development. I have created this site - www.hum3r.com

If you try to open the site in Chrome it loads and scrolls so slowly. But in IE, Safari, Firefox and even in Incognito Window of Chrome itself handles perfectly. Please advise why and any suggestion to fix slow  n unsmooth scrolls

Comment: Could be because you're loading 26 external scripts and 5 external stylesheets.  That's bad for performance... (FYI, wasn't any noticable difference between FF and Chrome when I tested).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like an extensions issue, probably with something that checks scripts as they are downloaded, like AdBlock Plus or a virus scanner. Check which extensions you are running; 99% chance one of them is to blame. Extensions are disabled in incognito mode, which is why it works okay.

Also, as @cale_b said, you should minify and bundle those scripts and stylesheets; those will put a hit on any browser.

Comment: Definitely minify and bundle too if possible.

Comment: Hi i run alexa and Adblock Plus. Does it load fast on urs? with no scrolling lag? Also, I used minfy plugin as its wp based. It screwed up my keyboard navigation scripts and also whats "bundle" ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't check it right now. "Bundling" refers to putting as many scripts as possible in one file and as many CSS files as possible in one file, to cut down on the number of round trips between client and server.

Comment: Try turning off those plugins temporarily and see what happens.